# How to implement role based authorization to edit fields

Tags: spring-boot, authorization, quarkus, put

i have got a Quarkus project where i want to implement role based authz. Lets say i have a class Product:

```
class Product {
String name
String description
String customerName
}
```

I have [authorized](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorize-web-endpoints-reference) the endpoint /products so that only Role A and Role B can do PUT operations. **My question is:**

**how can i ensure that Role A is only able to edit the field description, whereas Role B can edit the field name and customerName?**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, in many ways only if you are using RestEasy reactive. For example with @SecureField or @JsonView read the documentation:

[SecureField](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#secure-serialization)